# How to login With instagram and share wtih instagram Using IOS ? Objective c

Tags: objective-c

**1) Register to Instagram**

- To create Application using the Instagram API, you must have an account with Instagram.
- After creating your account in Instagram, login with Instagram account and open the URL: http://instagram.com/developer/
  Go to “Register your application” and click on the “Register New Client” button.
- You will be asked to provide Application Name, Description of your application, website and oAuth redirect_url. Here, the oAuth redirect_url specifies where to redirect users after they have chosen whether or not to authenticate your application.
- After successfully registering new client, Instagram will provide CLIENT INFO like CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET, WEBSITE URL, REDIRECT URI. Save CLIENT ID,CLIENT SECRET, REDIRECT URI to your application constants class as you will need this for authenticating to Instagram.

Lets see how can we authenticate…

**Step 1.**

At First set the authentication URL

Create a header file  and provide the header file name is ConstantHandle
    and set the all authentication URL

```
 #ifndef ConstantHandler_h
    #define ConstantHandler_h

    //set User authentication and url
    #define INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL @"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
    #define INSTAGRAM_APIURl  @"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
    #define INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID @"Client Id"
    #define INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET @"Clients Secret"
    #define INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL  @"Redirect URL"
    #define INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN  @"access_token"
    #define INSTAGRAM_SCOPE         @"likes+comments+relationships+basic"

    //Contant Url
    #define ACCESS_TOKEN    @"#access_token="
    #define UNSIGNED        @"UNSIGNED"
    #define CODE            @"code="
    #define END_POINT_URL   @"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"
    #define HTTP_METHOD     @"POST"
    #define CONTENT_LENGTH  @"Content-Length"
    #define REQUEST_DATA    @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    #define CONTENT_TYPE    @"Content-Type"

    //share Photo Constant
    #define DOCUMENT_FILE_PATH @"Documents/originalImage.ig"             
    #define APP_URL   @"instagram://app"                                         
    #define UTI_URL   @"com.instagram.exclusivegram"
    #define MESSAGE   @"Instagram not installed in this device!\nTo share image please install instagram."

    #endif /* ConstantHandler_h */
```

At first set the all micro

**Step 2.**

```
Add a file in your project

Provide the file name is
```

> InstagramController

```
create a file  inherit with UIViewController
```

Add the this code in InstagramController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ConstantHandler.h"

@interface InstagramController : UIViewController


- (void)loginWithInstagramWithParsentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller  completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *userProfileInformation))completionHanlder failureHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *errorDetail))failureHandler;

- (void)sharePhotoWithInstagaramWithImage:(UIImage *)image parsentViewcontroller:(UIViewController *)controller;;
@end
```

Add the this code in InstagramController.m file

```
 #import "InstagramController.h"

    @interface InstagramController ()<UIWebViewDelegate,UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
    {
        UIView                  *_progressView;
        UIWebView               *_webView;
        UIViewController        *_controller;
        UIActivityIndicatorView *_activitiyIndicator;
    }
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *typeOfAuthentication;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) void(^completionHandler)(NSDictionary *);
    @property (nonatomic, strong) void(^failureHandler)(NSDictionary *);
    @property(nonatomic,strong)UIDocumentInteractionController *docFile;

    @end

    #pragma mark - View Controller Life Cycle Method

    @implementation InstagramController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        //Add the cancel Button
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 70, 20)];
        [button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];

        //Setup The UIWebView
        [super viewDidAppear: animated];
        _webView = [UIWebView new];
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 64;
        _webView.frame = frame;
        _webView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_webView];

        //Hit instagaram API;
        NSString* authURL = nil;

        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        if ([_typeOfAuthentication isEqualToString:UNSIGNED])
        {
            authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True",
                       INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,
                       INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                       INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL,
                       INSTAGRAM_SCOPE];

        }
        else
        {
            authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code&scope=%@&DEBUG=True",
                       INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,
                       INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                       INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL,
                       INSTAGRAM_SCOPE];
        }


        [_webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: authURL]]];
    }
    #pragma mark - Local Method
    /*!
     Setup The genral Indicator View
     @retur  void
     */
    - (void)addIndicatorView {

        _progressView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 62)];
        _progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        _progressView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        _progressView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _progressView.alpha = 0.7;
        UILabel *lable = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,43, 80, 15)];
        lable.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [lable setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        lable.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
        lable.text = @"progress...";
        [_progressView addSubview:lable];
        _activitiyIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        [_activitiyIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(_progressView.frame.size.width/2.0, _progressView.frame.size.height/2.3)]; // I do this because I'm in landscape mode
        [_progressView addSubview:_activitiyIndicator];
        [_activitiyIndicator startAnimating];
        _progressView.center = self.view.center;
        [_webView addSubview:_progressView];
    }

    /*!
     This method is used to request to call back Url and check the authenTication
     @param  NSURLRequest is the check the request URl;
     @return BOOLk
     */
    - (BOOL) checkRequestForCallbackURL: (NSURLRequest*) request
    {
        NSString* urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

        if ([_typeOfAuthentication isEqualToString:UNSIGNED])
        {
            // check, if auth was succesfull (check for redirect URL)
            if([urlString hasPrefix: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL])
            {
                // extract and handle access token
                NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString: ACCESS_TOKEN ];
                [self handleAuth:[urlString substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length] withProfileInfo:nil];
                return NO;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if([urlString hasPrefix: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL])
            {
                // extract and handle code
                NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString: CODE];
                [self makePostRequest:[urlString substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length]];
                return NO;
            }
        }

        return YES;
    }
    /*!
     This method is used to get the User profile information
     @param   NSString is a authToken
     @return  void;
     */
    -(void)makePostRequest:(NSString *)authToken
    {

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=%@&code=%@",INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET,INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL,authToken];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        // URL of the endpoint we're going to contact.
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:END_POINT_URL];

        // Create a POST request with our JSON as a request body.
        NSMutableURLRequest *requestData = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        requestData.HTTPMethod = HTTP_METHOD;
        [requestData setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:CONTENT_LENGTH];
        [requestData setValue:REQUEST_DATA forHTTPHeaderField:CONTENT_TYPE];
        requestData.HTTPBody   = postData;

        // Create a task.
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:requestData
                                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                                         NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                         NSError *error)
                                      {
                                          if (!error)
                                          {
                                              NSDictionary  *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                              [self handleAuth:[dictionary valueForKey:@"access_token"] withProfileInfo:dictionary];
                                          } else{

                                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                              [self handleAuth:nil withProfileInfo:nil];
                                          }
                                      }];

        // Start the task.
        [task resume];

    }

    /*!
     This method is used to get The profile information is the request is completed
     @param  NSSTring authetication key
     @return void
     */
    - (void) handleAuth: (NSString*)authToken withProfileInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
    {
        NSLog(@"successfully logged in with Tocken == %@",authToken);
        if (dictionary) {

            _completionHandler(dictionary);
        } else _failureHandler(dictionary);
        // [self makePostRequest:authToken];
        [self cancelLogin];
    }
    - (void)cancelLogin {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIViewController *vc = [_controller.childViewControllers lastObject];
            [vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
            [vc removeFromParentViewController];
        });
    }
    #pragma mark -WebView Delegate Method

    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        return [self checkRequestForCallbackURL: request];
    }

    - (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {

        [self addIndicatorView];
    }

    - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        [_progressView removeFromSuperview];
        _progressView = nil;
        [_activitiyIndicator stopAnimating];

    }

    - (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        [self webViewDidFinishLoad: webView];
    }

    #pragma mark - user Define Method

    - (void)loginWithInstagramWithParsentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller  completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *userProfileInformation))completionHanlder failureHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *errorDetail))failureHandler {

        _controller = controller;
        [controller addChildViewController:self];
        self.view.frame = controller.view.frame;
        [controller.view addSubview:self.view];
        [self didMoveToParentViewController:controller];
        _completionHandler = completionHanlder;
        _failureHandler    = failureHandler;
    }
    - (void)sharePhotoWithInstagaramWithImage:(UIImage *)image parsentViewcontroller:(UIViewController *)controller{

        NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:DOCUMENT_FILE_PATH];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath]) {
            NSFileManager *fielManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fielManager removeItemAtPath:savePath error:nil];
        }
        BOOL save   = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:APP_URL];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL] && save) {

            self.docFile = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
            self.docFile.UTI = UTI_URL;
            self.docFile.delegate = self;
            [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:controller.view animated:YES];
        } else {

            NSLog(@"%@",MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionController delegateMethod

    - (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
        UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
        interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
        return interactionController;
    }

    #pragma mark - selector method
    -(void)cancel:(UIButton *)button {

        [self cancelLogin];
    }
    @end
```

**Step 3:**

```
Finally import "ConstantHandler.h" file in ViewController 

Add the Login and share Button in ViewController and  the this code

  #import "ViewController.h"
#import "InstagramController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) InstagramController *instagramHandler ;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)loginWithInstagram:(id)sender {

    _instagramHandler = [InstagramController new];
    [_instagramHandler loginWithInstagramWithParsentViewController:self completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *userProfileInformation) {
        NSLog(@"%@",userProfileInformation);
    } failureHandler:^(NSDictionary *errorDetail) {
        NSLog(@"%@",errorDetail);
    }];

}
- (IBAction)shareWithInstagram:(id)sender {

            _instagramHandler = [InstagramController new];
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flower-197343_960_720.jpg"];
            [_instagramHandler sharePhotoWithInstagaramWithImage:image parsentViewcontroller:self];
}

@end
```

**Step 4.**

Build and run the project

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Exactly; your "Question" looks a lot like a step-by-step answer.

Comment: @khurshid 

Hiii,
How can I use this cond in swift 3?

Answer (score 1):

Delete NSHTTPCookieStorage and Use App Transport Security.
 And add webView delegate before webView request. After use method, dealloc and set webView delegate to nil.